# Javascript forEach function overriding itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to programming here and trying to make my way through the Odin Project. In particular, I am trying to build an etch-a-sketch using just Javascript, CSS, and HTML.

I managed to generate a grid of divs using JS and create functions that modify the background colors of the divs to fill in the little squares with black, randomly generated rainbow colors, and finally a "shading" effect, where each time the mouse passes over the square, it increases the opacity of the square by 0.1, eventually turning it completely black.

Each of the above is triggered by an HTML button. However, I am finding that even though the shade function works when first clicked, once I then click the "black" button to turn the squares back to black (with an opacity of 1), if I then decide I want to use the shade effect again by clicking it again, the opacity of the squares remains at 1 and the shading effect no longer works (all squares still turn completely black).

It seems as though the one function is overriding the other, as the value of each square's opacity after clicking both buttons and after mouseenter in the dev tools turns to "1.3" for some reason. Essentially, I can't explain why the "shadeGrid" function no longer behaves as it should, and reset the opacity to 0 is being overridden.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Etch-a-sketch</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <button id="random">Random Colour</button>
    <button id="black">Black (default)</button>
    <button id="shade">Shade</button>
    <div id="container">

    </div>

</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT
FUNCTION TO CREATE GRID

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

function createGrid (size) {
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < size * size; i++) 
    {
        let createCell = document.createElement('div');
        // add class giving them 100% width/height
        createCell.className = 'cell';
        createCell.id = `${i}`;
        container.appendChild(createCell);
    }

};
```

FUNCTION TO SHADE SQUARES BY + 0.1 OPACITY ON MOUSEENTER

```js
const shade = document.getElementById("shade");
shade.addEventListener('click', () => shadeGrid());

function shadeGrid () {
    let gridCell = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    for (let i = 0; i < gridCell.length; i++) 
    {
        gridCell[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
        gridCell[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
    gridCell.forEach((cell) => {cell.addEventListener ('mouseenter', () => 
    {
       let oldOp = cell.style.opacity;
       oldOp = Number.parseFloat(oldOp);
       newOp = oldOp + 0.1;
       cell.style.opacity = newOp; 
    })
    });
}
```

FUNCTION TO MAKE SQUARES COMPLETELY BLACK ON MOUSEENTER

```js
const black = document.getElementById("black");
black.addEventListener('click', () => bgBlack());

function bgBlack() {
    let gridCell = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    
    gridCell.forEach((cell) => {cell.addEventListener ('mouseenter', () => 
    { 
        cell.style.opacity = 1;
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    })
    });
}
```

Comment: That's because you always add an EventListener to the `<div class="cell">` Element. You would have to remove the other EventListerns first.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `addEventListener` it doesn't replace the handler function put on the event, they all stack up. This means that in your code the same handler function can be set multiple times, and different ones too. And they all will execute in the order they are set.

What you need to do is to remove those handler functions before you set another, if you want to leave only one active.

This can be done with `removeEventListener`, but it needs the handler function to be named so that it works. Notice that I remove all of them in each case, to be sure. It's OK to remove a function handler if it has never been set, it will just do nothing, so you can remove them all.

Because the variable `cell` is no longer available where you define these handler functions, you can replace it by `this`. In an event handler function, `this` represents the element the handler has been attached to.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

function createGrid (size) {
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < size * size; i++) 
    {
        let createCell = document.createElement('div');
        // add class giving them 100% width/height
        createCell.className = 'cell';
        createCell.id = `${i}`;
        container.appendChild(createCell);
    }

};

createGrid(1);

const shade = document.getElementById("shade");
shade.addEventListener('click', () => shadeGrid());

function shadeListener () {
    let oldOp = this.style.opacity;
    oldOp = Number.parseFloat(oldOp);
    newOp = oldOp + 0.1;
    this.style.opacity = newOp; 
}

function shadeGrid () {
    let gridCell = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    for (let i = 0; i < gridCell.length; i++) 
    {
        gridCell[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
        gridCell[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
    gridCell.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.removeEventListener ('mouseenter', shadeListener);
      cell.removeEventListener ('mouseenter', bgBlackListener);
      cell.addEventListener ('mouseenter', shadeListener);
    });
}

const black = document.getElementById("black");
black.addEventListener('click', () => bgBlack());

function bgBlackListener() {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function bgBlack() {
    let gridCell = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    
    gridCell.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.removeEventListener ('mouseenter', shadeListener);
      cell.removeEventListener ('mouseenter', bgBlackListener);
      cell.addEventListener ('mouseenter', bgBlackListener);
    });
}
```

```css
#container { width: 300px; height: 300px; }

.cell { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="random">Random Colour</button>
<button id="black">Black (default)</button>
<button id="shade">Shade</button>
<div id="container">
  HOVER BELOW
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for such a clear answer! I had no idea about removing event listeners. One follow up question, if I may. Currently when you click on the shade button, the grid entirely resets to white. I am trying to make it so that this doesn't happen and the shading effect only affects those cells which have not already been touched by the "black" or "random" event listeners (i.e. the remaining white cells). I tried changing the starting opacity of all cells to 0 in the CSS, but this doesn't seem to work for some reason. Anyone know why?

Comment: The simplest way I think about it is to add a class (for example `noshade`) to the cell when "touched by the black or random effect". Then you can filter them out straight from the selection in you `shadeGrid` function by using `let gridCell = document.querySelectorAll(".cell:not(.noshade)");`. Don't forget to remove the class when you want to reset the grid